# Is it there any other ways from moving, changing and relating to other directories?

Tags: bash, computer-behavior

Accidentally I typed dir`/..` in the end, need to realize the real difference between, those paths:

```
$ command ../dir

$ command dir/..
```

They do two different things, using the same `..`

as well, it works for:

```
$ ls ~/..
```

> to list one directory up of $HOME, and maybe if I use $VARIABLE/.. as well.

### What else is possible? In the path Linux world.

I'm talking specifically about this `..`, `./`, `.`, `../`, or `/..`, if there are any other symbols like that, one that I don't know, or an advanced way or trick to use it in a better way, out of the common

And if they have proper names please share them.

> If isn't there any other, the answer should be "There's none"

Comment: Any suggestion how this question should be "asked" in a different way it's totally acceptable. And if you know the technical names of respective `../`, `..`, `.` please share them. I just believe there's more depth to that, but I may be wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's no special treatment for `..`, `../` or `/..`.

`../` isn't a single token. It's `..` (parent directory) followed by `/` (directory separator). Similarly, `/..` is two tokens too.

`..` is [just a directory name like any other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148563/53467), except it leads up the directory tree rather than down. The shell understands `cd ../dir` exactly the same way it would understand `cd foo/bar`: it's `[directory1]/[directory2]`.

Comment: Actually I vote this as right not only because you answered  especifically an important detail, your link does answer a lot as well @ctrl-alt-delor. I guess it will take me time to find more about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Path is parsed from left to right, so `../dir` means go up then go to `dir`; `dir/..` means go to `dir` then go up, which is the same as `pwd` or `$PWD`.

> What else is it possible?

Basically anything that is relative-path related.

EDIT:

`.` is a symbol meaning current directory and can also mean source if you want to run a bash file, `..` is a symbol meaning the upper directory, the same goes for `../`. `./` is two symbols explicitly meaning the current directory, no running bash like the former, `/..` is two symbols meaning go to the upper directory of the root, which will return root. Any other symbols like `...` `....` are likely aliases.

```
alias ...="cd ../.."
```

More information can be found using keywords like `directory actions on Linux` or `folder actions for Linux`.

Comment: Adding to this "~" means the users home directory.

Comment: Yes, and a single `/` means the root directory.

Comment: My question wasn't that simple and I completely understand all you said. I believe I should reformulate my questioin to "is there any other forms or ways of changing/moving from directories? What else is possible in the Linux bash", for me having a better understanding of the topic

Comment: There are absolute and relative paths in Linux. Changing directory is just `cd`, then you can use relative path or absolute path from this point.

Sometimes you may want to combine absolute path with relative path, then let's say I have an absolute path saved to `dirname` like `dirname=/etc`. I am currently in `~` and I want to go to `/etc/apt/`, then I will use `cd $dirname/apt/`.

Comment: Nice! Those types of answer @Smithienious is what I want. Need more examples, or methods. But just to add, I need some advanced methods as well, if they exist.

Comment: @Tyþë-Ø your question is very unclear - it seems like you almost want a tutorial on path navigation - The summary is that if the path starts with a "./" it means "relative to the current directory.   "../" means go up 1 directory.   Starting with "/" means start at the root directory.  Starting with "~/" implies start at this users home directory and starting with  "~user/" means start a specified users home directory.     Absolute paths - ie from the root of the filesystem start with "/" and everything else is relative to the current directory.

Comment: It's not unclear and you almost gave the answer, I'm talking specifically about this `..`, `./`, `.`, `../`, or `/..`, if there's any other symbols like that, one that I doesn't know, or a advanced way or trick to use it in a better way, out of the common. Once I know what is called these, and understand better the topic I'll simplify and reformulate my question.

Comment: @Tyþë-Ø `.` is a symbol meaning current directory and can also mean `source` if you want to run a bash file, `..` is a symbol meaning the upper directory, the same goes for `../`. `./` is two symbols explicitly meaning the current directory, no running bash like the former, `/..` is two symbols meaning go to the upper directory of the root, which will return root. Any other symbols like `...` `....` are likely aliases.

```
alias ...="cd ../.."
```

Comment: @Smithienious I know this is an akward question, so I would let things here, and I'll  have to do a research on my own. If you can update your question as this last comment, I'll mark as "right question". Please if you know more detailed info about it, share any links, Thanks!

Comment: @Tyþë-Ø thanks, and have fun.